# i should able to launch url when button pressed with using ib

Tags: iphone, url, uibutton, launch

i think there may be option like launch url in ib

can anybody answer it if u know,,,,,

Comment: may be some option we have to set in ir button options ,can any one answer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed {  
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.url.com"];  
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what "i want to display a launch url name", but if you want to open a URL in safari you can use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Comment: i downt want to load url page ,i am having one logo when i touches that logo it should launch url name in a small view or box....

Comment: So you want a small subview loading a webpage?